# How to get computed property data in method in Vue js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have a computed property

```
 computed: {
    totalwishlistItems () {
      const totalwishlistItems = this.items
      const totalreversedItems = totalwishlistItems.map((item, index) => totalwishlistItems[totalwishlistItems.length - 1 - index])
      return totalreversedItems.length
    }
}
```

And i want this `totalwishlistItems` data in a method

```
methods : {
getPosts () {
      for (let i = 0; i < this.totalwishlistItems; i++) {
        this.posts.push({first: 'John',
          last: 'Doe',
          suffix: '#' + i})
      }
    }
}
```

How can i get value of computed data in method in Vue js ?

Comment: `this.totalwishlistItems`

Comment: Not working sir

Comment: Well thats how you access your computed property, not like this `this.totalwishlistItems()`. Are you getting errors, or have you done any debugging

Comment: Computed properties as the name says are properties and not functions. So as @Tomm said you need to use `this.totalwishlistItems`. If it is not working tell us what error you are getting or how do you know it is "not working"

Comment: In my method i've done this - getPosts () {
      console.log(this.totalwishlistItems)
      for (let i = 0; i < this.totalwishlistItems; i++) {
        this.posts.push(i)
      }

Comment: I've console ` console.log(this.totalwishlistItems)` and got 0

Comment: in template i use {{ totalwishlistItems }} and get valid value , i want it in method so i can use it in loop

Comment: How is totalwishlistItems populated? Are you calling getPosts before filling totalwishlistItems? There could be some async problems that we can't see in your current question.

Comment: beforeMount () {
    this.items = this.$store.state.wishlist.items
    this.$bus.$on('user-after-loggedin', this.getUserName)
  },    This is how "totalwishlistItems" gets data Sir ,

Comment: Ok i have directly used "this.$store.state.wishlist.items.length" from before mount() which was responsible for providing the data to "totalwishlistItems"

Comment: @devmage can you just update the question with the required information rather then posting constantly posting these in the comments, its cluttering the comments and it won't make any of this easier.

Comment: Be careful with assigning an object to a local variabe. It will be a reference, not a copy, and can mess with your store state and reactivity. In your example, you could just compute on `this.$store.state.wishlist.items`, no need for local `this.items`

Comment: Your `totalwishlistItems` computed property should return `totalreversedItems`, *not* `totalreversedItems.length`, surely?

Comment: Also we still don't see how `this.$store.state.wishlist.items` is populated.

Comment: @Zed , i am not getting values using this.totalwishlistItems , that'y i had to use that object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the reverse, here is way to work with store data and computed properties.

```js
computed: {
    items () {
        return this.$store.state.wishlist.items
    },
    itemCount () {
        // assuming this.$store.state.wishlist.items is array
        return this.items.length
    }
},
methods: {
    getPosts () {
        for (i = 1; i <= this.itemCount; i++) {
            this.posts.push({
                first: 'John',
                last: 'Doe',
                suffix: '#' + i
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This shows how you can work with store data, and local computed properties. There might be other issues at populating the store data, and I dont see what is the relation between item count and post requests.

Comment: i've checked its working fine into frontend , not sure why you worry about some issue ?

Comment: what is the use of $store.dispatch ? @zed

Comment: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html#dispatching-actions

Comment: Thanks zed , for quick response

Answer (score -1):

You have to treat computed functions as a variable when you call them. A computed function can have a getter and a setter.

If you have a setter, you can trigger it using something like:

```
this.computedVar = 2;
```

If you have a getter, you can trigger it using:

```
this.computedVar;
```

As you can see, in both cases you treat it like a variable when you call it.

Comment: can i use it in methods ? using getter ( this.computedVar ) .